# Label's text overlaps with the text area when minimize the window

Tags: javascript, css, html, knockout.js

```
<label  class="form-control " style=" font-weight:normal; margin-left:-15px;" for="briefProjectDescription"
   class="col-sm-4">
  <em > *Note: If awarded funding, this description will be used in publicly available documents;
  please clearly summarize the project in the third person.</em>
</label>

 <textarea style=" width:72%; margin-top: 30px;  margin-left:5px; padding-right: 32px; " class="requiredfield"
  id="briefProjectDescription" maxlength="2000" data-bind="css: , attr: { title: briefProjectDescriptionToolTip },event: {focusout: checkLostFocus.bind($root, $data, 'briefProjectDescription')}, value: briefProjectDescription"></textarea>
```

I have a label above a text area. When the screen is normal, it is fine. When the window minimized, the text of the label overlaps above the text area. Thanks!

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem can you provide a link?

Comment: @DeepshikhaChaudhary the problem has been resolved by the answer below. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `form-control` of bootstrap is causing the issue.It has `height:34px` by default. You have to override by assigning  **`height:auto`** to the `label`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
 <label  class="form-control col-sm-4 " style=" font-weight:normal; margin-left:-15px; height:auto;" for="briefProjectDescription">
  <em > *Note: If awarded funding, this description will be used in publicly available documents;
  please clearly summarize the project in the third person.</em>
</label>

 <textarea style=" width:72%; margin-top: 30px;  margin-left:5px; padding-right: 32px; " class="requiredfield"
  id="briefProjectDescription" maxlength="2000" data-bind="css: , attr: { title: briefProjectDescriptionToolTip },event: {focusout: checkLostFocus.bind($root, $data, 'briefProjectDescription')}, value: briefProjectDescription"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solved the problem. I will accept the answer once I can. It doesn't allow me with such a period of time. Thanks again!

Comment: @TrEx You are welcome  :) , yes i think the time period is 15 mins